# Why install app in Launcher?

Tags: launcher, webapps

What is the advantage to install app on the pc to have the link in the launcher?
I mean, the first time I use Gmail Ubuntu suggests me to install the app in the  Launcher, but when I click it seems it only open a new webpage. There are other real advantage that I do not know? It seems like a simple bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

When you install it, you are given the option to add it to the launcher, so if you want it in the launcher, you can have it in the launcher. The fact the launcher does not work properly could be a bug with it, or it being the wrong launcher - do you get a similar result to when you select GMail normally in the dash/menu?

If you don't want it, you should be able to right click on the icon and remove it:
[image]

Comment: That's not the question @Ale asked, they asked what benefits are there.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to 'install' a web app, as well as creating a shortcut it will (for some apps) also give you features, e.g. for youtube it will let you play/pause from the volume menu and for gmail I think it will give you mail notifications. Also, they'll display toolbarless in Chromium (but not firefox)